# libgcrypt AES to return ascii ciphertext?

Tags: java, c++, cryptography, java-native-interface, gnupg

Hey, I m developing a JNI shared library which uses AES256 CFB mode to encrypt some data using libgcrypt and then passing the encrypted the data back into java app for further processing.

However, when I try to decrypt the data by passing it again to the shared library I can no longer get the original plain text back. It seems that if I encrypted and decrypted the same data without passing it back to the Java app I would get the original plain text back.

I was thinking that it was the conversion of the char buffer that I used to store the encrypted data to a NewStringUTF() (ie env->NewStringUTF(buf)) to send back to the java that was causing the issue so is there away to get/convert the output of the encrypted data to ascii or if there was some other work around?

Many thanks,
Foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using JNI and external libraries just to encrypt a string?  Use Java's built-in [`javax.crypto.Cipher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class.

However, regarding your actual question, you should be passing the data as a byte array, not a string.  Ciphers operate on bytes, not abstract Unicode codepoints.

Comment: it was mandated to use libgcrypt otherwise JCE would of been much easier :( the encrypt method in libgcrypt passes the encrypted data back in a char const buffer so I thought I could just return that as a new utf string. I will give byte arrays ago and see how that goes, cheers

Comment: @Foo, I'd try to push back on that mandate.  It's stupid and wasteful of developer time, and I doubt it brings any benefit.  Anyway, remember that `char` in C is a byte, not a Unicode character; the natural Java equivalent of a `char*` is a `byte[]`, not a `String`.  Converting it to a string is problematic because the sequence of bytes doesn't necessarily follow the rules of UTF-8 or UTF-16 or any other Unicode encoding.

Comment: your on money there. I modded it to return a jbytearray instead of a string and it works fine now. Cheers :)